# Google Plus share on business page using Share Button

Tags: google-plus, share-button

I have already created my Google plus business page and already implemented the "Share Button" on my website. The issue is that when i click on the share button, it gets posted on my profile and not on the business page. Can anyone please help me out, thank you.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate and not as clearly asked as your other question. Suggest closing or deleting this question and using the other question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Plus Share Button is not sharing on Business Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214851/google-plus-share-button-is-not-sharing-on-business-page)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Plus Share Button is not sharing on Business Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214851/google-plus-share-button-is-not-sharing-on-business-page)

Answer (score 1):

That's how it's meant to work. Imagine other people are clicking on your share button. It'll give you some lime-light on THEIR profiles.

If I've missed the point horribly please elaborate...

Comment: an example is; i have an online shopping system and many users are registered to it. i want a feature that when i add a new product or there's a promotion for a particular product, my google plus page gets updated in the sense that the details of the product are published there automatically. It will only be used for back-office purpose.

Comment: I see. For something like that you would need your site to be setup to submit entries to the business page on your behalf when new products are added. It would need to tie into the back end of your e-commerce solution. 

I would recommend looking for plugins for your shop that might offer that functionality. Why would you want a back-office only record on a public business page (I can understand the appeal for marketing)?