# Google Plus Share Button is not sharing on Business Page

Tags: google-plus, share-button

Suppose I have an online shopping system and many users are registered to it. I want a feature that when I add a new product or there's a promotion for a particular product, my Google plus page gets updated in the sense that the details of the product are published there automatically. It will only be used for back-office purpose.

The problem is that I cannot share on the Business Page, it gets posted on my user profile.

How can I achieve posting on google plus page via a web application?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you would need to use a [third party social media management tool](http://www.google.com/+/business/3rdpartytools.html) to achieve this in an automated manner. I've tried Hootsuite and it appears to work with a standard account.

If the number of products that you add is not high in volume, you could manually share by using the https://plus.google.com site and switching to use your page as the poster.

Answer (score 2):

## Set the page *free* as a *standalone* account

*Apparently* Pages may now (since when I don't know) have their umbilical cords severed, and set free to stand on their own two feet.

The process involves setting a password for the Page (via the Page's settings) that allows it to be signed into and out of rather than simply managed.

This *should* allow Shares to be made (and other G+ actions such as +1ing) from around the web **as the Page** instead of as the profile that created it.

See [an article on plusyourbusiness.com from Oct 2014](https://www.plusyourbusiness.com/share-blog-post-website-google-plus-page-profile/) for some details, and [an article on blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.de from Mar 2014](http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.de/2014/03/set-login-id-and-password-for-a-google-plus-page.html) (cited by the former) for some more.

P.S. The *"apparently"* and *"should"* are due to my not having walked through the process myself yet.

P.P.S. (done it now) Easy and works.